# How to resolve : No error message available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005). - SalesLogix 8.1

Tags: c#, console-application, oledb, saleslogix

I wrote a .NET Console application to update records in a SalesLogix 8.1 database. 
When it's run on a particular client, I get the exception message .

> "No error message available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005)."

I've seen this error when running without the provider installed but the server in question is a SalesLogix server itself. The application already targets x86.

My questions are as follows
1. Shouldn't the provider already be installed on the server?
2. How can I test for the provider directly?